# How can I put a string with attributes on the screen with auto-wrapping and cursor advancing with ncurses?

Tags: ncurses

As described [here](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_add_wchstr.3x.html), add_wchstr functions do not advance the current cursor position or do auto-wrapping.

But if I want to output text like [addwstr](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addwstr.3x.html) do, but with format attributes, what should I call?

If ncurses is stupidly missing such feature, I consider implementing it manually (Simply calling add_wch for each character and advance the cursor position). But the key problems are:

How can I indicate whether an auto-wrapping is required?

How can I indicate whether a character is displayed over 2 cells (full-width characters) so that I should correctly call add_wch twice (or any other alternative solutions that displays full-witdh characters correctly)?

How can I indicate where the current cursor postion should be advanced to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set

- the window attributes with [wattrset/wattr_set](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_attr.3x.html),

  > These  routines  manipulate the current attributes of the named window,
  >      which then apply to all characters that are  written  into  the  window
  >      with  waddch,  waddstr  and  wprintw.  Attributes are a property of the
  >      character, and move with the character through any  scrolling  and  in-
  >      sert/delete  line/character  operations.   To the extent possible, they
  >      are displayed as appropriate modifications to the graphic rendition  of
  >      characters put on the screen.

or

- the background character with [wkbgdset](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_bkgd.3x.html#h3-bkgdset)/[wbkgdset](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_bkgd.3x.html#h3-bkgdset).

  > ```
  >   The bkgdset and wbkgdset routines  manipulate  the  background  of  the
  > ```
  >
  > named window.  The window background is a chtype consisting of any com-
  >      bination  of  attributes  (i.e.,  rendition)  and  a  character.    The
  >      attribute part of the background is combined (OR'ed) with all non-blank
  >      characters that are written into the  window  with  waddch.   Both  the
  >      character  and  attribute parts of the background are combined with the
  >      blank characters.  The background becomes a property of  the  character
  >      and  moves  with  the character through any scrolling and insert/delete
  >      line/character operations.